# Changing Locale within the app automatically to english

Tags: android, localization, arabic

I Integrated Locale (`en` and `ar`) on my application. Once I change the application to Arabic(`ar`) then close and open my application it showing the layout direction is showing as Arabic but the strings are loading English.

Here is my code to change the language while button click,

```
public static void setLocale(final Context ctx, final String lang) {
    Log.d(TAG, "##Changing Language to: " + lang);
    AppSettings.getInstance(ctx).save(PrefKeys.language, lang);
    final Locale loc = new Locale(lang);
 
    Resources resources = ctx.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        configuration.setLocale(loc);
    else
        configuration.locale = loc;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        ctx.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
     else
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
}
```

Also on the Application class I added code to apply the language, Here is the code on Application Class

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    String lanuage = AppSettings.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getLanguage();
    setLocale(new Locale(lanuage));
}


private void setLocale(Locale locale){
        Log.d(TAG,  "##Changing Language to: " + locale.getLanguage());
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
        } else{
            configuration.locale=locale;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        } else {
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,displayMetrics);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about creating a base activity and extend it with your activities then add language  change on the base activity

Comment: @anwarsamir I didn't tried it

Comment: @anwarsamir When I change to BaseActivity, its working fine. Thanks for your advice

Comment: You are welcome, could you please upvote  the comment and accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new `BaseActivity.class` and extended that class to Home Screen,

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        String language = AppSettings.getInstance(newBase).getLanguage();
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.wrap(newBase, language));
    }


    private static class LocaleHelper extends ContextWrapper {

        public LocaleHelper(Context base) {
            super(base);
        }

        public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(language.trim())) {
                return new LocaleHelper(context);
            }
            Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                config.setLocale(locale);
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                config.locale = locale;
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
            return new LocaleHelper(context);
        }

    } // LocaleHelper

}
```

Here is the code modification on HomeActivity,

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_home;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a base activity and extend it with your activities then add language change on the base activity

something like below

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


companion object {
    var lang: String? = null
}


override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(localeManager!!.setLocale(base!!))

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
  Utility.resetActivityTitle(this)
}
```

}